# CountDownLatch vs AtomicInteger and some boilerplate

Tags: java, multithreading

Can I use AtomicInteger (Which is Synchronized and volatile) instead of countdownLatch in this example. Am I missing something? Is there any other scenario where I cannot replace the countdownLatch with an AtomicInteger?

```
static void runProducer(final int sendMessageCount) throws InterruptedException {
    final Producer<Long, String> producer = createProducer();
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(sendMessageCount);

    try {
        for (long index = time; index < time + sendMessageCount; index++) {
            final ProducerRecord<Long, String> record =
                    new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, index, "Hello Mom " + index);
            producer.send(record, (metadata, exception) -> {
                long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
                if (metadata != null) {
                    System.out.printf("sent record(key=%s value=%s) " +
                                    "meta(partition=%d, offset=%d) time=%d\n",
                            record.key(), record.value(), metadata.partition(),
                            metadata.offset(), elapsedTime);
                } else {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            });
        }
        countDownLatch.await(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }finally {
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: atomic integer doesn't offer this nice functionality: `countDownLatch.await(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` ...but much more beyond.

Comment: Post the `AtomicInteger ` version

Comment: How would you implement this with `AtomicInteger`? Right now, your thread _blocks_ on `await(...)`. I don't see how you could do that with only `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Thanks folks. I posted too soon I guess. I will post the atomic Integer version shortly

Comment: The whole point of `CountDownLatch` is the part where everybody _waits_ for the count to reach zero. The big selling point of `AtomicInteger` is that its operations  are guaranteed to _never_ make a thread wait. They all either immediately succeed, or immediately fail.